# How would I undo or edit the last line of a multi-line query in mysql?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I often make mistakes when entering multi-line queries in mysql. Is there an easier way to undo the last line instead of retyping the entire query?

```
mysql> SELECT age, name
    -> FROM people
    -> WHERE age > 20
    ->
```

For example, I meant to type `age < 20`, is there a way to quicky fix that? Normally I would ctrl + C and use the up arrow key to re-enter first two lines quickly, but I feel like there should be an easier way.

I tried reading documentation and read some forums but I couldn't find anything. It should be a new feature if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Next line can be `- 21 AND age < 20;`. Or `+ NULL OR (age < 20)`. There is a lot of variants.

Comment: interesting approach... I was just using a simple example, but my actual quieres are usually larger and more complex, so this method won't always work. Thanks though!

Comment: Use a different tool, maybe mycli.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type ***edit***.

```
mysql> edit
```

It would open a vi editor. You can make any number of mistakes and undo them.
Once done with your multiline query, exit(:wq) out the editor.
Type ***;*** to execute your query.

```
mysql> ;
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for